# File downloading returns IOException with Android 2.3

Tags: android, download, ioexception, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a code that downloads and reads text files, but it returns IOException with Android 2.3. It works well with other versions.

Duplicate of this same problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841925/java-io-ioexception-bufferedinputstream-is-closed-in-android-2-3) but none of those tips helped and I'm currently trying the trick at [this page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562). I also have the custom DoneHandlerInputStream class in my code.

Code:

```
URL url = new URL(URLstr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

BufferedReader rd;

InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
stream = new DoneHandlerInputStream(stream);
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
}
rd.close();

String resultedString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream. Don't know if that was what you want to know though.

Comment: Darn it. I just noticed that there were two reasons for this problem. This really fixed the other one, but somehow the "exists(URLstr)" that I use in my app always results false with Android 2.3 and my app ends up downloading file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
have u try this?

while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line);
    if (!rd.ready()) {
       break;
    }
}
rd.close();
```

Comment: Actually I fixed my problem already. This really worked for me, but the result of it was IOException, because it tried to download a file that didn't exist. My app downloads many files and somehow when the app tries to check which files exist, the result is always false and that messed up my app.

Comment: That's not even funny compared to the mess I have actually had here. I wasn't even using BufferedReader originally. I had DataInputStream, which doesn't have this problem at all, but when I got the IOException in Android 2.3, I changed the DataInputStream to BufferedReader because of a "solution" here. In addition to another IOException, that gave me problems with text files containing ä and ö and also led me to wrong tracks with solving the problem. Fail! It was just bad luck that both exists() and BufferedReader have problems with Android 2.3.